# django-rest-framework- Filtering using 'or' on multiple values from one url parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a tagging system in place for a model that my API exposes.  The models look something like this:

```py
class TaggableModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="taggable_models")

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

I've then set up a serializer and view that look like:

```py
class TaggableModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TaggableModel
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'tags',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class TaggableModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TaggableModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaggableModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    filter_backend = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['tags']
```

If I want to grab all `TaggableModels` that have tag ids 1, 2, or 3, I can do so via:

`https://my-api-domain/api/taggable-models?tags=1&tags=2&tags=3`

Is there a way to split on a delimiter, so I can pass it all as one parameter?  e.g.:

`https://my-api-domain/api/taggable-models?tags=1,2,3`

It looks like I can write my own custom DjangoFilterBackend filters, but I am a bit unsure as to where to start.  Or perhaps there is an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can do this by having custom filterset class with specific field 'widget' (that's how it is called in django-filters)

Here's a sample you can try:

```
# filters.py

from django_filters.rest_framework import FilterSet, filters
from django_filters.widgets import CSVWidget

from .your_models import Tag, TaggableModel

class TaggableModelFilterSet(FilterSet):
    tags = filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Tag.objects.all(), widget=CSVWidget,
        help_text=_("A list of ids, comma separated, identifying tags"),
        method='filter_tags'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = TaggableModel
        fields = ['tags']

    def filter_tags(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value:
            queryset = queryset.filter(tags__in=value)
        return queryset
```

```
# views.py

class TaggableModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TaggableModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaggableModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_class = TaggableModelFilterSet
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it isn't well documented.

For someone looking to just convert their existing field: the key settings that make this work are: specifying ModelMultipleChoiceFilter, Including the queryset for the object and setting the widget.

Answer (score 1):

There is an even simpler way to achieve this using the [`django-filter` package](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). Deep within the [`django-filter` documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filterset.html#declaring-filterable-fields), it mentions that you can use "a dictionary of field names mapped to a list of lookups".

Your code would be updated like so:

```
# views.py

from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class TaggableModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TaggableModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaggableModelSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    filter_backend = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = {
        'tags': ["in", "exact"] # note the 'in' field
    }
```

Now in the URL you would add `__in` to the filter before supplying your list of parameters and it would work as you expect:

```
https://my-api-domain/api/taggable-models?tags__in=1,2,3
```

The `django-filter` documentation on what lookup filters are available is quite poor, but the `in` lookup filter is mentioned in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) itself.